# SAS combine two columns in a dataset

Tags: sas

I got a dataset looks like this:

| Category | Sub-Category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | xx |
| A | 2 | xx |
| A | 3 | xx |
| A | 4 | xx |
| B | 1 | xx |
| B | 2 | xx |
| B | 3 | xx |
| B | 4 | xx |

I want to combine the first two columns and create a new dataset with the new category(rows) and it should looks like this:

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| 1 | xx |
| 2 | xx |
| 3 | xx |
| 4 | xx |
|  |  |
| B |  |
| 1 | xx |
| 2 | xx |
| 3 | xx |
| 4 | xx |
| ... |  |

Can anyone help me with that using SAS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like a report, not a data set. Is this for display in a PDF/WORD/Excel doc? If so, PROC REPORT or TABULATE may be better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems pretty useless as a DATASET.

Why not just print the original dataset.

```
proc print data=have;
  by category;
run;
```

Result:

[image]

If you did want to generate that goofy dataset you could try interleaving two copies of the original data.

```
data want;
  set have(in=in1) have(in=in2);
  by category;
  if in1 then do;
    if first.category then call missing(value);
    else delete;
  end;
  if in2 then category=cats(subcategory);
  drop subcategory ;
run;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a data step with multiple output statements. The only tricky part is the first row: you'll need to retain the original value to create the "header" row, output, then output a second time to create the first subcategory row.

```
data want;
    set have end=eof;
    by category subcategory;

    if(first.category) then do;

        /* "Header" row: */
       _value_ = value;
        value = ' ';
        output;

        /* First subcategory row: */
        value    = _value_;
        category = strip(subcategory);

        output;
    end;

        /* Subsequent subcategory rows */
        else do;
            category = strip(subcategory);
            output;
        end;

    /* Add a space between categories except the last row */
    if(last.category AND NOT eof) then do;
        call missing(value, category);
        output;
    end;

    drop _value_ subcategory;    
run;
```

Result:

```
category    value
A   
1           xx
2           xx
3           xx
4           xx

B   
1           xx
2           xx
3           xx
4           xx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input Category $ SubCategory value $;
datalines;
A 1 xx
A 2 xx
A 3 xx
A 4 xx
B 1 xx
B 2 xx
B 3 xx
B 4 xx
;

data want;
   set have;
   by Category;
   if first.Category then do;
      v = value;
      value = '';
      output;
      value = v;
      Category = put(SubCategory, 8. -l);
      output;
   end;
   else do;
      Category = put(SubCategory, 8. -l);
      output;
   end;
   drop SubCategory v;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Proc REPORT` can produce the desired rendering of the data set.

```
proc report data=have;
  columns category subcategory value;
  define category / order noprint;
  compute before category;
    line category $200.;
  endcomp;
run;
```

[image]

#### Some alternative renderings

```
proc print data=have;
  by category;
  id category;
  var subcategory value;
run;
```

[image]

---

```
proc tabulate data=have;
  class category subcategory;
  var value;
  table
    category
    * subcategory
    ,
    value
  ;
run;
```

[image]

---

```
data haveR;
  set have;
  by category;
  if first.category then output;
  output;
run;

title "Report - indent";
proc report data=haveR;
  column category subcategory cat value;
  define category / order noprint;
  define subcategory / display noprint;
  define value / display;
  define cat / computed style=[just=left] 'Category/hierarchy';
  compute cat / length=200;
  endcomp;
  compute value;
    if not missing(category) then do;
      priorcategory = category;
      cat = category;
      value = .;
    end;
    else do;
      cat = repeat('A0'x,3) || cats(subcategory);
    end;
  endcomp;
run;
```

[image]